# How to manipulate the laravel query builder output data using php

Tags: laravel

Assume I have a simple laravel query builder.

```
$data = DB::table('users')->get();
```

(I want to use only query builder and not eloquent since the query will be very complex in reality)

and the table fields are `userid, firstname, lastname, gender`

before I pass the  $data to my view I would like to modify the output data using PHP

Say I wanted to add the prefix  Mr or Miss to firstname depending on the gender column or something like that.. (please don't suggest a pure sql solution since the complexity of the condition will be much more complex that just adding a prefix.. I had given this as a simple use case only)

Is it possible ?

Comment: If you decided to use Eloquent, accessors would be great solution for this - http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just iterate the result

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
  if ($value->gender === 1) {
    $value->lastname = 'Mr ' . $value->lastname;
  } else if ($value->gender === 0) {
    $value->lastname = 'Miss ' . $value->lastname;
  }
}
```

Comment: forgot the obvious :)